# Changing log file location of couchbase

Tags: couchbase

To change the server log location , I follow the following step But my log location is not change
Step :-

Log in as root or sudo and navigate to the directory where you installed Couchbase. For example: /opt/couchbase/etc/couchbase/static_config
Edit the static_config file and change the error_logger_mf_dir variable to a different directory. For example: {error_logger_mf_dir, “/home/user/cb/opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/logs”}
Restart the Couchbase service. After restarting the Couchbase service, all subsequent logs will be in the new directory.
But my logs still generating in the same directory (default directory) ?